# What happens to XP earned after reaching the level 50 cap when adding DLC that raises the cap

Tags: borderlands

If you have a level 50 character and you continue to play missions without any DLC what happens to the XP earned?

When "The Secret Armory of General Knoxx" is purchased and the level cap raises what happens to the XP earned in the interim? Do you gain several levels at onces as the XP is applied or do you start at level 50 from scratch?

Comment: Pretty sure nothing happens. As in BL2, you can see your XP display, stuck at a certain number, in the menu.

Comment: @BenBrocka yeah, in BL2 I'm at the cap now, but in BL1 I got the GotY edition so I started with all the DLC. I want to know how it worked in BL1 without the DLC - my guess is that BL2 will work the same way.

Comment: @BenBrocka for BL2 (rather than BL1) see [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89159)

Answer (score 5):

You do not get to save up xp once at level cap.  All experience earned is negated, and you don't earn any more until the cap is raised.

Answer (score 0):

You can't earn XP beyond level 50 unless you add the DLC which raises the level cap potentially to level 69.

Also, if you haven't already, play with someone who's level 69 and if you are at level 50, you will get XP from that players kills if you've added the DLCs which take your cap up to level 69. For example a level 68 player killing a level 69 enemy or boss may not net them huge XP, but the lower your level, especially if you're only level 50 has the potential to net you tons of XP at once and save you some serious grinding between levels.